# Why does C++20's concept constraint not work as expected?

Tags: c++, constraints, overloading, c++20, c++-concepts

```
#include <concepts>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
requires requires(T const& t) {
    !std::is_enum_v<T>;
    { std::to_string(t) } -> std::same_as<std::string>;
}
void Foo(T const&) {
}

template<typename T>
requires std::is_enum_v<T>
void Foo(T const&) {
}

enum Color {
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue,
};

int main() {
    Foo(Red); // error: Call to 'Foo' is ambiguous
}
```

Obviously, the two overloaded `Foo` are mutually exclusive; that is to say, if `std::is_enum_v<T>` is `true`, the former should not be selected. But `clang-18 -std=c++20` gives an error.

Why does C++20's concept constraint not work as expected?

Comment: *"But clang-18 -std=c++20 gives an error..."* All compilers give an error saying "ambiguous call"

Comment: Why does the former's constraint `!std::is_enum_v<T>;` not work as expected?

Comment: `!std::is_enum_v<T>` check is the expression is well formed, not its value...

Comment: `!std::is_enum_v<T>;` checks this expression for validity, not for truthyness. Move it outside `requires{...}`: `requires (!std::is_enum_v<T>) && requires(...){...}`, OR prepend another `requires`: `requires !std::is_enum_v<T>;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `!std::is_enum_v<T>` in the `requires` block is well formed and thus accepted. To check the value you need to write `requires(!std::is_enum_v<T>)`. Both things can be combined as in the below example:

```
template<typename T>
requires(!std::is_enum_v<T>) && 
requires(T const& t) {
    { std::to_string(t) } -> std::same_as<std::string>;
}
void Foo(T const&) {
}
```

[See Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/f5YKzoo55)

Comment: I don't think you need parenthesis around `!std::is_enum_v<T>`.

Comment: gcc & clang complained while msvc was fine without brackets, [see demo](https://godbolt.org/z/99jTKMh48). Maybe this is a bug? Who is right?

Comment: I'd guess that gcc and clang are right, but it is a bit surprising to me.

Comment: I wrote it without the brackets first and was surprised too

Comment: @0xbachmann It is ill-formed as per current rules. See [Requires compile with msvc but rejected by gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78155107/requires-compile-with-msvc-but-rejected-by-gcc)