# Requires compile with msvc but rejected by gcc

Tags: c++, constraints, language-lawyer, c++20, requires-clause

I've written the following program that uses `requires` without parentheses. The program compiles with msvc but not with gcc and clang. I want to know which compiler is right here. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cjKaPKTjz)

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T> requires !std::is_enum_v<T>  
void foo(T)
{

} 
int main()
{
    foo(4); //msvc compile but not gcc and clang 
}
```

GCC says:

```
<source>:3:31: error: expression must be enclosed in parentheses
    3 | template<typename T> requires !std::is_enum_v<T>
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                               (                 )
Compiler returned: 1
```

---

Note that I am not looking for a workaround as I know that I can solve this by writing parentheses around `!std::is_enum_v<T>.` I want to know which compiler is right here for academic purposes.

Comment: I don't know but with a proper concept syntax all three compilers are happy : https://godbolt.org/z/ejWj55qqe

Comment: @PepijnKramer Do note that OP is not looking for a workaround though. As they can solve this by just adding parenthesis around.

Comment: @user12002570 Fair enough (I kind of suspect a compiler bug or different interpretation of the standard).

Comment: @PepijnKramer TBH this seems to be a standard defect to me, perhaps? I don't see why standard disallows `!std::is_enum_v<T>` but allows `std::is_enum_v<T>`.

Comment: @user12002570 Because it's easier to make a simpler rule -- there are certain things that must be parenthesized to avoid ambiguity and negation is weird so it doesn't seem worth special casing.

Comment: Just to put it out there, the use of parenthesis can also be avoided with the verbose `requires std::negation_v<std::is_enum<T>>`, which doesn't require any helper object and works with most standard type traits.

Answer (score 29):

The program is **ill-formed** as per the current grammar rules as shown below.

From [requires-clause documentation](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.pre#nt:requires-clause):

> ```
> requires-clause:
>    requires constraint-logical-or-expression
> ```

Now we move onto [constraint-logical-or-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.pre#nt:constraint-logical-or-expression):

> ```
> constraint-logical-and-expression
> constraint-logical-or-expression || constraint-logical-and-expression
> ```

Next, we move onto [constraint-logical-and-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.pre#nt:constraint-logical-and-expression):

> ```
> primary-expression
> constraint-logical-and-expression && primary-expression
> ```

So, now we go to [primary-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#nt:primary-expression):

> ```
>  primary-expression:
>    literal
>    this
>    ( expression )
>    id-expression
>    lambda-expression
>    fold-expression
>    requires-expression
> ```

Now, the expression `!std::is_enum_v<T>` **fits neither of the above listed constructs.** One might think that it is an *id-expression* but that is [not the case](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#nt:unqualified-id).

---

This means that we can't use `!` etc before `std::is_enum_v<T>` without parentheses.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T> requires !std::is_enum_v<T>  //invalid per grammar rules
void foo(T)
{
}

template<typename T> requires std::is_enum_v<T>  //valid per grammar rules
void bar(T)
{
}
```