# Expression without parentheses works in one case but not in other

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, requires-clause

I recently [came to know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78155107/requires-compile-with-msvc-but-rejected-by-gcc) that for complex expression(like expressions involving operators) in a *require-clause* the standard requires the use of parentheses.

But then I wrote the following program where the use of `||` works without parentheses but the use of `==` is not allowed. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7xhnG8zK4)

```
template<typename T> struct C
{
 constexpr static bool b = T{} + 1;     
 constexpr static bool c = T{} + 1;
}; 
//template<typename T> requires C<T>::b == C<T>::c  void f();    //all compilers reject this
  template<typename T> requires C<T>::b || C<T>::c  void bar();  //all compilers accepts this  
int main()
{
    // f<int>(); //fails in all three compilers   
    bar<int>();  //works in all three compilers 
}
```

I want to know why is the `==`  version not compile but the `||` version does?

Comment: The grammar explicitly allows `||` but not `==`(and other operators) in a require-clause.

Comment: This coincides with `requires` having custom behavior for `||` and `&&` (it decomposes them into individual constraints). But since they're decomposed even inside `(...)`, I have no idea why they didn't allow omitting `(...)` for other operators.

Comment: Which answer are you looking for:  the "grammar allows it" (the reason) or "the requires clause has that particular grammar to avoid ambiguities" (the rationale behind the reason)?

Comment: @Eljay Not the rationale but where the standard allows one but not other.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Are you saying that perhaps the `==` snippet given in the post should also have been allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know why is the == version not compile but the || version does?

Because the [standard grammar](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.pre#nt:constraint-logical-or-expression) **explicitly allows** `||` in a require-clause **without parentheses but not** `==` as explained below..

From [requires-clause](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.pre#nt:requires-clause):

> ```
> requires-clause:
>   requires constraint-logical-or-expression
> constraint-logical-or-expression:
>   constraint-logical-and-expression
>   constraint-logical-or-expression || constraint-logical-and-expression
>                                    ^^
> ```

As you can see, the use of `||` is allowed. Basically, **the `requires` has custom behavior for `||` and `&&`.**

---

But note `==`(and other operators) **without parentheses is not allowed** as also explained in the [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78155107/requires-compile-with-msvc-but-rejected-by-gcc). For reference, there is also a non-normative note in the standard:

> [ Note: **The expression in a requires-clause uses a restricted grammar to avoid ambiguities. Parentheses can be used to specify arbitrary expressions in a requires-clause.**
> [ Example:
>
> ```
> template<int N> requires N == sizeof new unsigned short
> int f();            // error: parentheses required around == expression
> ```
>
> — end example]
> — end note]

Comment: Do you have examples of where the less restricted grammar causes ambiguities?